# problem with two My SQL queries

Tags: mysql

I have table  **prod** with structure
**Id, name, keyword, yearborn.**

It is necessary to bring the number of keywords grouped encountered in the field **yearborn** , for example

```
SELECT yearborn, COUNT(Id) cnt1 FROM prod WHERE keyword='admiral'
GROUP BY yearborn
```

and

```
SELECT yearborn, COUNT(Id) cnt2 FROM prod WHERE keyword='captain' GROUP BY yearborn
```

How do I combine these two queries to get the output result table with the structure

**yearborn, cnt1, cnt2**?

I have tried UNION

```
SELECT yearborn, COUNT(Id) cnt1 FROM prod WHERE keyword='admiral' GROUP BY yearborn
UNION
SELECT yearborn, COUNT(Id) cnt2 FROM prod WHERE keyword='captain' GROUP BY yearborn
```

But result is:
**yearborn, cnt1**

Tell me please how to get out of this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT yearborn, 
         SUM(IF(keyword = 'admiral', 1, 0)) cnt1, 
         SUM(IF(keyword = 'captain', 1, 0)) cnt2 
    FROM prod 
   WHERE keyword = 'admiral'
      OR keyword = 'captain'
GROUP BY yearborn
```

The result will be something like this (of course this is fictitious data):

```
+----------+------+------+
| yearborn | cnt1 | cnt2 |
+----------+------+------+
|     2004 | 1233 |    0 |
|     1999 |    0 |   15 |
+----------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SUM() on your keyword conditions to do this, because the result of comparisons in MySQL can be treated as 0 (false) or 1 (true):

```
SELECT yearborn, SUM(keyword='admiral') cnt1, SUM(keyword='captain') cnt2 FROM prod GROUP BY yearborn
```

This also has the advantage of only using one table scan (it's faster than using unions and subqueries).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT yearborn, COUNT(Id) cnt1, NULL cnt2 FROM prod WHERE keyword='admiral' GROUP BY yearborn
UNION
SELECT yearborn, NULL cnt1, COUNT(Id) cnt2 FROM prod WHERE keyword='captain' GROUP BY yearborn
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT yearborn,SUM(cnt1),SUM(cnt2) FROM
( 
    SELECT yearborn, COUNT(id) cnt1, 0 cnt2 FROM prod WHERE keyword='admiral' 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT yearborn, 0 cnt1, COUNT(id) cnt2 FROM prod WHERE keyword='captain'
) 
GROUP BY yearborn
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try this:

```
SELECT `yearborn`,
COUNT(`Id`) AS `cnt1`
FROM `prod`
WHERE `keyword` IN ('admiral','captain')
GROUP BY `yearborn`,`keyword`;
```

edit:
added the `keyword` in GROUP BY statment.